# Entity Framework Join statement

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, expression

```
kitchenlist = from listkitchens in kitchenlist
                          join tblkitContacts in db.tblKitchenContacts on listkitchens.Id equals tblkitContacts.KitchenId  
                          join tblKitMedia in db.tblKitchenMedias on listkitchens.Id equals tblKitMedia.KitchenId
                          join tblKitRemits in db.tblKitchenRemittances on listkitchens.Id equals tblKitRemits.KitchenId                         
                          where tblkitContacts.Latitude != null && tblkitContacts.Longitude != null && tblKitMedia.KitchenId != null
                          && tblKitRemits.KitchenId != null                         
                          select listkitchens;
```

I have this code which is joining the Three tables with Main Table tblKitchen and working as per Condition.

If I try to join another table tblKitchenCuisines which has multiple rows for same Kitchen Id the
complete response gives multiple times for each kitchen depending on number of rows inside tblKitchenCuisines.

```
var result = kitchenlist.ToList().Select(x => new KitchenAllModel
            {
                KitchenId = x.Id,
                KitchenName = x.KitchenName,
                KitchenType = x.KitchenType,
                Area = x.Area,
                Address1 = x.Address1,
                Address2 = x.Address2,
                //CId = x.CityId,
                Pincode = x.Pincode,
                Email = x.Email,
                Website = x.Website,
                Landline = x.Landline,
                Halal = x.Halal,
                Category = x.Category,
                Branches = x.Branches,
                AvgCost = x.AvgCost,
                Fssai = x.Fssai,
                FssaiPath = x.FssaiPath,
                RegisterStatus = x.RegisterStatus,
                Rating = x.Rating,
                Offer = x.Offer,
                KitchenStatus = x.KitchenStatus,
                AreaZone = x.AreaZone,
                Logo = x.tblKitchenMedias.Where(r => r.KitchenId == x.Id).Select(r => r).FirstOrDefault().Logo,
                Banner = x.tblKitchenMedias.Where(s => s.KitchenId == x.Id).Select(s => s).FirstOrDefault().Banner,
                KDis = ("5.0").ToString(),
                GetAllcontact = x.tblKitchenContacts.Where(y => y.KitchenId == x.Id).Select(y => new KitchenContactModel
                {
                    KitchenId = y.KitchenId,
                    KicthenOwner = y.KicthenOwner,
                    LegalName = y.LegalName,
                    ContactPerson = y.ContactPerson,
                    Mobile = y.Mobile,
                    Manager = y.Manager,
                    ManagerMobile = y.ManagerMobile,
                    OwnerMobile = y.OwnerMobile,
                    Landline = y.Landline,
                    StartTime = y.StartTime,
                    EndTime = y.EndTime,
                    DeliveryTime = y.DeliveryTime,
                    Latitude = y.Latitude,
                    Longitude = y.Longitude,
                    MapString = y.MapString,
                    ContactStatus = y.ContactStatus,
                }
                            ).ToList(),
                GetAllCuisines = x.tblKitchenCuisines.Where(z => z.KitchenId == x.Id ).Select(z => new KitchenCuisinesModel
                {
                    KitchenId = z.KitchenId,
                    CuisinesId = z.CuisinesId,
                    Id = z.Id,
                    CuisinesName = z.Cuisine.Name,

                }
                            ).ToList(),
                GetAllRemittance = x.tblKitchenRemittances.Where(a => a.KitchenId == x.Id).Select(a => new KitchenRemittanceModel
                {
                    KitchenId = a.KitchenId,
                    LegalName = a.LegalName,
                    BankName = a.BankName,
                    AccountNo = a.AccountNo,
                    IFSCCode = a.IFSCCode,

                }
                            ).ToList(),
                //GetAllMedia =x.tblKitchenMedias.Where(b=>b.KitchenId==x.Id).Select(b=> new KitchenMediaModel
                //{
                //    KitchenId =b.KitchenId,
                //    Banner=b.Banner,
                //    Logo=b.Logo,
                //    Id =b.Id,

                //}
                //).ToList(),

            }
            ).ToList();
            return result;
```

I want to Join tblKitchenCuisines and add a condition to ignore Kitchen which has Zero Entries in table and also not cause multiple repeats .

Please help

Comment: ASP.NET is a web stack, it doesn't load data. That's what EF is for. EF is an ORM though, it doesn't need joins. It generates them from the relations between entities. A DbContext isn't a database connection, an entity isn't a table. If you have to use JOINs, your model is missing relations

Comment: Joins is working Fine Since one table has multiple rows which i am joining with main table linked to Id , I Need to take only firstOrDefault Row which i am not able to do using joins statement ( Lamdba Expression )

Comment: No it's not. Otherwise you wouldn't be posting here. EF has no tables, it has entities with relations. That's why you never see a join between Blog and Post in tutorials, you see `blog.Posts`. The join will be generated by EF itself. You wouldn't have to load entire tables into memory with `ToList()`

Comment: In My Expression how i can select or JOIN only 1st row and 4th Joining Table ? Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Fix your relations so you don't need joins. If you wanted to eagerly load all kitchens and their related objects you could add an `.Include()` for eany relation you also want to load, eg `db.Kitchens.Include(k=>k.Contacts).Include(k=>k.Meddia).Where(...)...`. No JOINs required. If you don't want to eagerly load the relations, you can simply iterate over the results and EF will load the necessary objects one by one.

Comment: I want to Join tblKitchen with tblCuisines which has multiple rows of Reference Key to tblKitchen. 
Can you please give a correct query for above query expression? 

" join tblKitCuisines in db.tblKitchenCuisines on listkitchens.Id equals tblKitCuisines.KitchenId "